# Invoking EJB with changed interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, interface, ejb

Today I made some experiments with EJBs.

JavaEE 6

Websphere 8.0.x

I have an interface defining some remote methods:

```
interface Calculator{
  int add(int x, int y);
  int mul(itn x, int y);
}
```

This interface is implemented by an EJB.

Furthermore I have another EJB calling the Calculator-EJB
from another application (ear). So in total I deployed
two ear files, everything works fine.

Now I changed the Calculator interface, I dropped the mul-method,
but in the implementing EJB class the mul-method is still implemented,
I just removed the @override annotation.
Now I redeployed the ear with the EJB implementing the changed interface.

To my surprise the other ear application is still able to invoke
the mul-method.

Is this part of the EJB standard?

After that I renamed the Calculator interface to Calculator2
and redeployed the EJB implementing this new interface.

The other ear application, which only have the old Calculator
interface, is still able to invoke the methods on the newly
deployed EJB which implements just the new Calculator2 interface.

Same question: Is this part of the EJB standard?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the "No interface view" of the EJB3.1 specification.

All methods that are public for a EJB can be accessed without an interface.
But I'm not sure whether you can have the NoInterfaceView in parallel with the Interfaces, that might not acording to the spec.

Comment: true, it behaves like a no-interface view, but the client is in another appliaction/ear and uses an (old) interface for injection. Strange that it works